# punctuation marks(RegExp) are counted as word

Tags: java, android, regex

I created an app that gets Texts and counts number of words in it. My app has an Edit Text to enter text and a Text View to show number of words. I have to problem with my app: 1. Punctuation marks like "!?.," with space after them are counted as a word which shouldn't be and 2.after deleting text from edit text my text view shows 1 which is number of word but edit text is empty. Please help.

Here's my code:

```
package com.farmani.wordcounter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;
EditText et;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
     et = findViewById(R.id.et);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String text = et.getText().toString();
            text = text.replace("\n"  , " ");
            String[] textArray = text.split(" +|,|\\.");
            tv.setText("Number of Words: " + textArray.length);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final String text = "Hello! This is some text with words.";

final String[] split = text.split("\\W"); // Split by "non-word" characters

int wordCnt = 0;
for (String s : split) {
  if (!s.isEmpty()) { // If two adjacent non-word characters are encountered the string in between is empty, so we don't count it.
    wordCnt++;
  }
}
```

See also https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it gives error to 's' in this line : for (String s : split)
and this is the error: variable is already defined in the scope